# How to ssh into a Traefik pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

I am using GKE. I've launched the following traefik deployment through kubectl:

https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/examples/k8s/traefik-deployment.yaml

The pod runs on the kube-system namespace.
I'm not able to ssh into the pod.

`kubectl get po -n kube-system
traefik-ingress-controller-5bf599f65d-fl9gx   1/1     Running   0    30m`

`kubectl exec -it traefik-ingress-controller-5bf599f65d-fl9gx -n kube-system -- '\bin\bash'
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"\\\\bin\\\\bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
command terminated with exit code 126`

Am I missing something? The same thing for '-- sh' too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently the default traefik image is an amd64 version. I had to use the alpine version to ssh into it using:
 `kubectl exec -it _podname_ -- sh`

Comment: Tried this solution but it didn't work.. We are getting following error - "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126

Answer (score 2):

rather use forward slashed `/` (your example has a backslash) such as in

```
kubectl exec -it traefik-ingress-controller-5bf599f65d-fl9gx -n kube-system -- '/bin/bash'
```

If this does still not work, try a different shell such as

```
kubectl exec -it traefik-ingress-controller-5bf599f65d-fl9gx -n kube-system -- '/bin/sh'
```

Comment: Yes.
kubectl exec -it traefik-ingress-controller-7fc5d6f569-tlr4t -n kube-system -- '/bin/sh'

rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"

command terminated with exit code 126

Comment: Do you find any shell with `-- 'ls /bin/'` ?

Comment: I get the following error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls /bin/\": stat ls /bin/: no such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry, i dont know this partical image. Are there any images based on alpine linux? Does at least `-- 'ls /'` outputs something?

Comment: No. Even -- 'ls /' doesn't do anything. Even i had tried all these before and couldn't find any solution. I'm probaby missing something trivial. Not sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: None of those commands work for Traefik pods.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [this here](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-ssh-into-the-container-running-the-traefik-controller/862/2) is the right answer. You cannot exec a shell into the traefik container using the default image, you must use the `alpine` one.